# discord bot user reaction

Tags: python, bots, discord

So I am trying to make my personal "splashbot" for my discord server. This is one of the commands that it should do. The problem is that I don't know how to check if the player choose one of the reactions. I tried some things out and here is the code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['paidsplash'])
async def splash(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('Are you sure you want to do a paid splash?')
    emoji1 = '✅'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    emoji2 = '❌'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji2)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    client.wait_for("reaction.users()=='✅'",  timeout=10.0) #reaction.users()?
    await ctx.send('yes')
```

Basically the player types '*splash', the bots removes that and asks the question + adds those 2 reactions on it. Then the player must pick a reaction. They will be added to a queue if ✅ but I haven't come to that part...
Preferable just copy and edit to code in your answer, so I can see what is wrong, I learn the fastest that way

Comment: The code you need can be found within the discord.py documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Answer (score 0):

The `client.wait_for` code is incorrect. You're supposed to define a check function first, then pass that through to the `wait_for` function so that it can check for a reaction.

This is some sample code from the discord.py documentation (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) edited to work for your situation. Essentially, it's just the same thing as the example code but waits for a reaction not done by the bot (or the author of the message in the code)

```
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user != message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```

Comment: So I edited it to this: https://pastebin.com/JcRXHKWb
But the problem now is that it already recognizes the reactions put by the bot and not waits for a player to react on it: https://gyazo.com/53e39baf5965d66f94f6a7079cb41929

Comment: Changed the code so that it waits for a reaction not from the bot. @IGDT